# How can I get the JSON of an article from the API when I just know the node_slug?

Tags: python, json, khan-academy

I have a list of node_slug values of Khan Academy articles like:

- `a/square-roots-of-perfect-squares-art`
- `a/number-of-solutions-to-a-system-of-equations`
- `a/distance-formula`

Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way from this piece of data to get the API JSON. For that, you need an id like "xe504dd90". This is different from `exercises` and `videos`, which both have a dedicated API.

What it's possible is to get the page from the main website, which has all the data I need and much more, but it's more difficult to parse. What I need are the main metadata of the page (title, author, image_url, etc.).

Comment: (I understand this is not exactly a programming question, unfortunately I tried everything and SO is the best place to get an answer...)

Comment: Not sure what your question is. To get the KA-id for arts like the one you mention (ie, correlate slugs to those ids), there is an undocumented v2 API, mentioned in one of the last comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34231475/get-ka-exercise-hierarchy) ... but unfortunately it is currently broken.

Comment: FYI the v2 API is reported broken; you may want to follow-up [here](https://github.com/Khan/khan-api/issues/114)

Answer (score 0):

I can't reply to your comments, but the aforementioned v2 API endpoint which gets all KA content works now. It's a pretty large payload, almost 7MB at this time, and takes a little while to respond.

http://www.khanacademy.org/api/v2/topics/topictree

You could search through the articles array with your node_slugs, find its respective ID, and go from there.

I know this is an old question, but I figured my answer might help someone else one day. Vote up if this helps you out!